# #1064 - error when importing .ibd or .frm file to database

Tags: php, mysql

There was a problem in my WAMP so I copied my DATABASE folder to another location and reinstalled WAMP.

After that, when I tried to import it, there was this error of

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?A?' at line 1

Tried everything there is on google, and Stack overflow but couldn't solve this.

Comment: How did you try to import your database?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [dba.se] but due to low quality isn't worth migrating.

Answer (score 1):

SORRY bro you cant directly copy or restore file level to database.you have to first take backup in dump form and then try to import.

[Here you can check how to dump database](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/import-and-export-databases-using-phpmyadmin/)

Comment: That is true for MySQL and many other databases, but not for all. MonetDB would be an exception where you can copy database files and restore them on a file-level :-)